# Why there should be degradation of dharma with the change in the yuga?

Tags: yuga, dharma

It a well known fact that there are four ages satya, treta, dwapara and kali.

But why there is a demarcation in the ages, one explanation is that there is decline of dharma.

The dharma stands on four legs in satya and declines to one leg in kali.

But why should the dharma decline with ages? Who decided it?

Why should the mindset of the people should change with ages?

Comment: because if not, the world will be monotonous. just as villains are necessary to watch a movie, the cycles of yugas and so on are present in Nature. The world is like a giant movie. A big illusion movie show. There are different actors playing their parts. There is nothing real in the world, except You, who is called God.This is advaita.

Comment: @Sai what is the problem if world is monotonous ? Why one appreciate the differences if all belongs to the same absolute nature ?

Comment: would you watch a movie in which there is no event, just a regular life where one person wakes up and goes to work and the movie ends? Think of life as a big movie where there are good and there are bad. 'Why one appreciate the differences if all belongs to the same absolute nature'. The absolute nature of everyone is Brahman or God. However when speaking of the world, the nature of the world is duality or Good and Bad. :) That is why the saints say that to realize one's true nature one has to go beyond good and bad. All the best